# Apache CustomLog pipe to script fail

Tags: python, apache

I am trying to add a CustomLog to my apache httpd.conf file that pipes the logformat into a script. The test.py script is extremely simple right now becuase I am just trying to get it to work. When I run the script from the command line it works exactly as expected. When apache calls the script its calling it as root. I've set the user/group to root on that script and as a precaution I've done a chmod 777 on the script. The problem is as soon as I restart httpd the error_log file starts to fill up with this error. I've even tried to go so far as to make the script file an empty file but I still get this error. As a side note I do have another CustomLog pipe in my config file that splits and rotates my logs and it is working perfectly fine.

#### apache/logs/error_log output

```
AH00106: piped log program '/hwnet/dtg_devel/web/boarddev/applications/test.py' failed unexpectedly
```

#### httpd.conf

```
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vcombined
CustomLog "|/hwnet/dtg_devel/web/boarddev/applications/test.py" vcombined
```

#### test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
with open("/hwnet/dtg_devel/web/boarddev/applications/test.log", "a") as output_log:
    output_log.write("Hello World\n")
```

#### System Configuration

```
python: 2.6.6
apache: 2.4.7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up discovering the problem had to do with my script. The way apache works is it starts the script as a background process and that process is supposed to be running so apache can push new logs into it. My script was written in a way that it would run once then exit. Because of this everytime apache tried pushing a new log record to it, it wasnt running in the background to receive it thus causing the error.

Comment: How did you keep it running?